# LINQ to find all childs related to parents ID

Tags: c#, linq

I have a many to many relation in my database between experiences and subjects.

From a list of experiences i will press a button for a particular experience and then be taken to a list that shows all subjects related to the chosen experience. By pressing the button i recieve the ID for the experience.

I have tried something like this, which obviously didnt work;

```
var subjectList = db.Subjects.Where(s => s.Experiences== id).SelectMany(s => s.Subjects).ToList();
```

Anyone knows how to find all subjects related to the experience using the ID, or is there some other way?

**Experience**

```
public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
public virtual User ApplicationUser { get; set; }

public Experience()
{
    this.Subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
}
```

**Subject**

```
public virtual ICollection<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }


public Subject()
{
   this.Experiences = new HashSet<Experience>();
}
```

Comment: Are you using any framework to connect with DB??

Comment: please post your models

Comment: Yes, entity framework

Comment: Do you need that `SelectMany` clause? Seems like `Subjects.Where(…).ToList()` should do the trick

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for your answer, but the Subject-class does not contain an id for the experience

Comment: @RufusL I honestly dont know what I need to write to find what im searching for, so dont even assume my example to be a qualified guess. XD

Comment: Could you show these two modle classes?

Comment: @Kacper I have added them now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in many to many relationships, the related EF classes have a navigation property that represents the collection of objects associated with each item.

In your sample code, you were referencing `Subject.Experiences`, but you were missing the piece that correlates the experience id correctly.

Something like this should do the trick, where `id` is the selected experience id:

```
var subjectList = db.Subjects
    .Where(s => s.Experiences.Any(experience => experience.Id == id))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `Include` in your EF/Linq query

so

```
var results = ctx.Experiences.Include(e => e.Subjects).Where(e => e.Id == _id);
```

then you can access all the `Subjects` by [edit] `results.Select(x => x.Subjects)` which will give you `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Subjects>>`. It can be flattened using `SelectMany(x => x)`.

this is assuming your class looks something like:

```
public class Experience {
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: In that case, wouldn't that create a List of JobExperiences? Because i need to pass a list of Subjects

Comment: I edited my answer, you could also use the `Select(x => x.Subjects)` immediate after `.Where(..`

Answer (score 0):

Use Include and ThenInclude

```
 var subjectList = db.Subjects
    .Where(s => s.Experiences== id)
    .Include(s => s.NavigationToMiddleTable)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.RelatedTable)
    .ToList();
```

Remember your Entity classes must have navigation properties to MiddleTable and the last RelatedTable